# runTransactionBlock causing delays in main thread

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where when a user clicks on a UIButton, 
 1. I update a child ( say tapCount) in Firebase

2. Load a ViewController with an image.

I am using a transactionBlock to increment this count as multiple users could be incrementing this count at the same time. What I notice is because there is a slight delay in completing this Firebase transaction, the app waits to complete it and then loads the View Controller when an image is clicked. It almost makes the app a little sluggish. So what's the recommended way to do this without causing any UI issues ? Is there a way to run this in a background thread ? Thanks

```
func incrementTapCount() {
        _tapCount += 1

        // update the link
        ref.runTransactionBlock { (currentData:MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
            currentData.childData(byAppendingPath: "tapCount").value = self._tapCount
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
    }



 func moreCommentAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let postCategory = self.globalPost.postCat 


        if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid != nil {

            //user is logged in
            // this increments the Like count when a button is tapped. 
            self.globalPost.incrementTapCount()
//            let likeCount = self.globalPost.favoriteBoost + self.globalPost.favoriteDict.count + self.globalPost.tapCount
//            likeButton.setTitle(" \(likeCount)", for: UIControlState())
        }
        else {
            //user is not logged in, so skip incrementing the tapCount.

        }

        let moreCommentVC = sender.storyboard?!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MoreCommentViewController") as! MoreCommentViewController
        moreCommentVC.globalPost = self.globalPost
        sender.present(moreCommentVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: you can open viewcontroller first and then update the count from the viewcontroller

Comment: if i added it in there, say in viewdidLoad or viewDidAppear, wouldn't still have the same delay ?

Comment: `runTransactionBlock` is async which means it will return immediately

Comment: hmm, doesnt look like it, cause if it did, then I would not have the issue in the first place. I tried adding it in viewdidLoad in the other controller, but I see the same issue. It's like it waits for it to return and that does take like 1-2 seconds. What I need is - i update it, and i don't want to have to wait. If its unsuccessful, its fine.

Comment: can you post more code ?

Comment: Added some more code. Take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can see the same issue with obj-c. runTransactionBlock() returns immediately but before the andCompletionBlock() is called, the main thread is blocked for 1-2 secs.

Did not happen before, started to see it after update to newer firebase version. In my case I managed to make this lag shorter by decreasing amount of data to update. It seems firebase is doing something like local cache update on the main thread (just a theory).